# How to edit txt file inside the HDFS in terminal?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Is there any way to modify the txt file inside HDFS directly via terminal? 
Assume, I have "my_text_file.txt", and I would like to modify it inside HDFS using below command.

```
$ hdfs dfs -XXXX user/my_text_file.txt
```

I am interested to know "xxxx" if there exists any.
Please note that I don't want to make modification in local and then copy it to HDFS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot edit files, which all are already in HDFS. It will not support. HDFS works on "Write once, read many". So if you want to edit a file, make changes in your local copy then move it to HDFS.

Comment: Does this mean the `ctime` and `mtime` will be the same for all the files for HDFS? I do not see an option to see the `ctime` of a file in HDFS. Will `mtime` be the `ctime` in this case since the files cannot be modified in HDFS?

Comment: HDFS stores only access time and modified time. Below Hadoop code will give more idea https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server/namenode/INodeAttributes.java#L61-L65

Comment: `mtime` and `ctime` are totally different. `mtime` is effectively the time of when the file was last closed

Answer (score 2):

Currently as explained by @BruceWayne, its not possible. It would be very difficult to edit the files stored in `hdfs` because all the files are `distributed` in `hdfs` and it would be very difficult to edit in the terminal using `hdfs` commands. Currently [these](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html) are supported as terminal commands.

You can edit them by locating the data location of each `datanode` in the cluster.But that would be troublesome.

Moreover you can install [HUE](http://gethue.com/how-to-configure-hue-in-your-hadoop-cluster/). With `HUE` you can edit the files in `hdfs` using `web UI`.

Answer (score 2):

You can not edit files in HDFS, as it works on the principle of Write once, Read Many.But now a day, we can edit file using Hue file browser in cloudera.